# Responsive Text in Inputfield

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, input-field

I have an input field and in this I add values via JavaScript.
How can I do it, if my input field is "full" at for example 30 characters, that the font will be smaller, so that everything is always visible?

```css
input {
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: You can use a `textarea` instead to be able to see all the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
input {
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:5px;
}
</style>

<input type="text" name="input" id="input">

<script>
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {
    $.fn.inputfit = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            minSize   : 10,
            maxSize   : false
        }, options);

        this.each(function() {
            var $input = $(this);

            if ( !$input.is(':input') ) {
                return;
            }

            $input.off('keyup.inputfit keydown.inputfit');

            var maxSize = parseFloat(settings.maxSize || $input.css('font-size'), 10);
            var width   = $input.width();
            var clone   = $input.data('inputfit-clone');

            if (!clone) {
                clone = $('<div></div>', {
                    css : {
                        fontSize     : $input.css('font-size'),
                        fontFamily   : $input.css('font-family'),
                        fontStyle    : $input.css('font-style'),
                        fontWeight   : $input.css('font-weight'),
                        fontVariant  : $input.css('font-variant'),
                        letterSpacing: $input.css('letter-spacing'),
                        whiteSpace   : 'nowrap',
                        position     : 'absolute',
                        left         : '-9999px',
                        visibility   : 'hidden'
                    }
                }).insertAfter($input);

                $input.data('inputfit-clone', clone);
            }

            $input.on('keyup.inputfit keydown.inputfit', function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                clone.text($this.val());

                var ratio = width / (clone.width() || 1),
                    currentFontSize = parseInt( $this.css('font-size'), 10 ),
                    fontSize = Math.floor(currentFontSize * ratio);

                if (fontSize > maxSize) { fontSize = maxSize; }
                if (fontSize < settings.minSize) { fontSize = settings.minSize; }

                $this.css('font-size', fontSize);
                clone.css('font-size', fontSize);
            }).triggerHandler('keyup.inputfit');
        });

        return this;
    };

}));

$('input').inputfit();
</script>
```

Best I could do it, Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No worries, Glad I could help x

Comment: One problem is still there, it doesn't work if i my input is readonly and i add the values with js..